# How to make a form-data request with koa?

Tags: node.js, multipartform-data, koa

I am trying to replicate a login form's behaviour through koa.

The login form does:

`<form id="loginForm" method="post" action="http://myaddress:3000/auth" enctype="multipart/form-data">`

I'm using the [koa request](https://github.com/dionoid/koa-request) and [form-data](https://github.com/felixge/node-form-data) modules:

```
var form = new FormData();
form.append('identification', 'userId');
form.append('password', 'userPassword');

var options = {
    url:            DB_SERVER_URL + 'auth',
    method:         'POST',
    formData:       form
};

var response = yield request(options);
console.log('response.statusCode: ' + response.statusCode);
```

But I always get a 400 response.

I've tried just using `form.submit(DB_SERVER_URL + 'auth', function(err, res) { ... }` which works, but I like koa's yield functionality and ideally I want to avoid having to deal with callbacks.

Any ideas?

Comment: So I was thinking, hey OP really is trying to do the same thing as I am, cool... and then I read your name.

Comment: Haha, what are the chances :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Koa accepts multiple yield inputs that can be obtained from your current code more or less easily depending on your current setup:

- a promise. As form-data doesn't seem to use them, we'll create one with [Q](https://github.com/kriskowal/q)

  ```
  var Q = require('q');

  var promise = Q.ninvoke(form, "submit", DB_SERVER_URL + 'auth');
  var response = yield promise;
  console.log('response.statusCode: ' + response.statusCode);
  ```
- or a thunk, a wrapper function as you used in your answer, but there are libraries that can handle the wrapping for you (here, [thunkify-wrap](https://www.npmjs.org/package/thunkify-wrap)):

  ```
  var thunkify = require('thunkify-wrap');

  var submit = thunkify(form.submit, form); // the context is needed in this case
  var response = yield submit(DB_SERVER_URL + 'auth');
  console.log('response.statusCode: ' + response.statusCode);
  ```

Comment: Awesome, I've used Q for the form submit.  I'm having trouble with the `response.on("data", callback)` because the callback does not provide an error.  Any idea how I'd use Q or thunkify for that?

Comment: thunkify-wrap can handle events, something like `var evnts = thunkify.event(response, 'data');  var data = yield evnts();`

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using `form.submit(DB_SERVER_URL + 'auth', function(err, res) { ... }`, but wrapped the callbacks so I could use `yield` to maintain a synchronous control flow.

Here's my wrapper for the callback to the `form.submit` to receive the response:

```
function makeLoginRequest(formData) {

    var form = new FormData();
    form.append('identification', formData.identification);
    form.append('password', formData.password);
    var DB_SERVER_URL = 'http://myurl:3000/';

    return function(callback) {
        form.submit(DB_SERVER_URL + 'auth', function(error, response) {
            callback(error, response);
        });
    }
}
```

And here's my wrapper for the callback for receiving the response body:

```
function getLoginResponseData(response) {

    return function(callback) {
        response.on("data", function(chunk) {
            callback(null, chunk);
        }); 
    }
}
```

This lets me use `yield` to maintain a synchronous control flow:

```
var response = yield makeLoginRequest(this.request.body);
console.log('response.statusCode: ' + response.statusCode);

var chunk = yield getLoginResponseData(response);
console.log("BODY: " + chunk);
```

I'm a node and koa beginner, so if you have a better way please let me know!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using koa-request I was able to do this.

```
const request = require('koa-request');

const response = yield request({
 method: 'POST',
    url: 'https://whatsever.com',
    form: {
     itema: 'vala',
     itemb: 'valb',
    },
    headers: {
      'Content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    }
  });

this.body = response.body;
```

If you need multipart look here: https://www.npmjs.com/package/request#multipartform-data-multipart-form-uploads.

Remember that `koa-request` wraps the`request`  module